# How to add a C:/ drive in Linux?

Tags: windows, wine

I'm new to Linux os. I install wine to run a windows program then an error occurred. Then I found that it's error occurred because c drive is not exist. The program need to write something into the c drive.

In other words, I'm needed to run the program but the program need to write things in c drive then my Linux os don't have c drive.

Any solutions? 
(I can accept if needed to install a program)

Comment: Have defined  WINEPREFIX=/home/yourusername/.wine  before running your program?  The directory drive_c is under .wine and becomes your C drive when running wine.

Comment: You might want to post the exact error message.

Comment: Hi ubfan1, can I view the c drive in .wine?

Comment: Open a terminal  and type `cd $HOME/.wine/drive_c` followed by the Enter key. You'll be at the "root" of the C drive that wine uses. You will need to learn a few Linux commands to do anything there. Start with `ls` which lists the files.